# How to use two or more packages and declare both in manifest? - android

Tags: java, android, package, manifest

The first package is **com.first.one** and the 
second one is **com.second.two**

Both the packages use the same xml files..

My problem is that my code in the first package works fine but the second package doen't..

I think the problem should be in the manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.first.one"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

As only the first package **com.first.one** is used and the second is not used.
if that is the problem. How can I declare both the packages in manifest?

If this is not the problem then why doesn't my code in the second package work?

Comment: Package name in AndroidManifest.xml only act like a unique application identifier, it doesn't need to be the same with the one you used in source code, you can have as many package as you want in your source code, and reference them using the complete package.class name in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind having separate packages is that secondary package(s) should supplement your application.  For example, if you are writing an application that is to use a website API, you could keep that package, say com.websiteAPI and draw from its resources as necessary, by importing:

```
import com.package_name_requested_here.R.*
```

Another example would be to write a package specifically for global objects, say com.objects.

To contrast this, your own package (the one specified in the manifest) should contain any and all files that are specific to your application.  Remember that you can set up the package to include subpackages though.  For example, if you made:

```
package="com.mystuff"
```

You could reference your activities in the manifest by writing:

```
<activity android:name=".first.one" </activity>
<activity android:name=".second.two" </activity>
```

Hope this helps. ^_^

Comment: thanks man.. is it possible to open an activity in second package from an activity in first package?

Comment: got it :) used this to open an activity in the second package.


**<activity android:name="com.second.two.Activity_Name" </activity>**

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Instead, you can add `import com.first.one.R.*;` to the classes in the second package to allow them to use the same same resources as the first one.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to have two app . you can use a build file that allows you to change package name in the manifest

target

```
<target name="name1_2" depends="">
        <replaceregexp file="AndroidManifest.xml" match='com.first.one' replace='com.first.second' byline="true" />
    </target>

<target name="name2_1" depends="">
        <replaceregexp file="AndroidManifest.xml" match='com.first.second' replace='com.first.one' byline="true" />
    </target>
```